# Why is __weak pointer in ARC not being set to nil?

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In xcode 4.5.1 , about ios ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005388/in-xcode-4-5-1-about-ios-arc)

here is my code(arc)

```
self.string1=@"aaa";
__weak NSString *temp= self.string1;

NSLog(@"string1  %@",self.string1);
NSLog(@"temp     %@",temp);

self.string1=nil;
NSLog(@"---after self.string1 = nil----");
NSLog(@"string1   %@",self.string1);
NSLog(@"temp      %@",temp);
```

I think the output should be as below:

```
string1  aaa
temp     aaa
---after self.string1 = nil----
string1   (null)
temp      (null)
```

However, when I run it in xcode4.5.1, it makes me confused

```
string1  aaa
temp     aaa
---after self.string1 = nil----
string1   (null)
temp      aaa
```

can anyone help me ,and tell me why temp=@"aaa" (it is __weak, and it should be nil after the string1=nil)

Edit:
hi,everyone. will we discuss in a wrong direction?
maybe the NSLog is defined in core Foundation Functions Reference. ARC  has some rules for parameter of core foundation functions Just as NSLog ? we pass _weak object into NSLog as parameter, it will change _weak into _autorelease?

Comment: that one was closed ,because the network error,I just sent the question for many times.it caused some issue, so I send again clearly.anyone who knows the reason about this arc question,just give me some advice

Comment: It was closed because it wasn't a good question. However I see you tried to edit it, and this one _is_ a real question, so since your old one is unlikely to get reopened, I'll answer it! Welcome to stack overflow, it's a tough crowd sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

`@"aaa"` is a compile-time constant, and will never be released. So, even if your weak pointer is the only thing you have, it will still be a valid object.

Try the experiment again with run-time created string, using `alloc / initWithFormat:` or similar, and you should see the results you expect.

**UPDATE**

Having tested this myself now it *still* doesn't seem to work as expected. There is further discussion of this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202810/lifetime-of-weak-local-variables-with-arc)

Comment: hi,I know what u think, but I have changed the code:self.string1=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",@"aaa"]; the result still shows the temp is "aaa".

Comment: by the way, I am using  xcode4.5.1(ios6)

Comment: I originally thought this, but I was thrown off by the debugger.  However, it was because my breakpoint was in the wrong place.  I didn't realize that the variables seem to be getting set to nil before my breakpoint on the last line.  So, this is the correct answer.  Trying this experiment with NSData shows it getting deallocated immediately.

Comment: try to pass NSData into NSLog as parameter.the result is different.